# Using a variable in Dynamic Query in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2005, dynamicquery

What I'm trying to do from this query is i'm trying to get all the rows which are older than the specified Cutoffnumber from customertransaction table:

```
@Cutoffnumber INT

SELECT @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM customertransaction WHERE DATEDIFF(DD, Transactiondate, GETDATE()) > @Cutoffnumber '
```

But i'm getting the below error, Note that this is a dynamic SQL query.

> > Must declare the scalar variable "@Cutoffnumber"

How should I go about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into [sp_executesql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

```
Decalre @Cutoffnumber INT    
Set @Cutoffnumber = @someValue
SELECT @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM customertransaction WHERE DATEDIFF(DD, Transactiondate, GETDATE()) >' + @Cutoffnumber
```

Though it seems like you could do this without dynamic SQL:

```
Declare @Cutoffnumber INT    
Set @Cutoffnumber = @someValue
SELECT * FROM customertransaction WHERE DATEDIFF(DD, Transactiondate, GETDATE()) > @Cutoffnumber
```

Comment: Appreciate your effort but thats not what I intended to do.